# Overriding admin .phtml files not showing up in magento2 backend?

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I have overridden the admin .phtml files

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml

but nothing shows.

This is my module.xml

> app/code/TemplateMonster/Orderitem/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TemplateMonster_Orderitem" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true">       
    <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
        </module>
</config>
```

This is my sales_order_view.xml file

> app/code/TemplateMonster/Orderitem/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales_order_items_renderer">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">TemplateMonster_Orderitem::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This my file path fordefault.phtml(

> app/code/TemplateMonster/Orderitem/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml

I don't know what is the mistake. Please someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below changes apply in app/code/TemplateMonster/Orderitem/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TemplateMonster_Orderitem" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

And below is the code for app/code/TemplateMonster/Orderitem/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">TemplateMonster_Orderitem::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now run below commands using SSH.

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f

chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Now, this time you will show an output. And also if this answer will be helpful then don't forget to upvote :)

Comment: Still not showing

Comment: Is there any error you are facing in var/log/exception.log file ? And also have you checked is there any theme used at admin side or what?

Comment: There is no error in exception.log file

Comment: There is no theme used at admin side

Comment: Possible help I have did. Now, up to you to find solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, In my local it was not working. When I pushed to live its working perfectly fine. Thanks:)

Comment: You, are Welcome :)

Comment: Hi, i have one doubt. The custom attributes is not showing for bundle product, and for configurable product its only showing for main product. Do you got any idea regarding this.